# Update the content attribute of the meta tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this:

```
<meta name="description" content="NEED_TO_UPDATE_THIS" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
```

and i need to update the content of meta tag that has the name="description" using jQuery. How can i use the selectors to choose that content atribute of that tag?

thanks

Comment: Why? I'm not aware of anything to makes any use of that except search engines and CMSes which don't execute JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, the meta description is also used by e.g. Facebook when someone shares a link. But I suspect they don't execute Javascript either, so that might be a moot point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'new value');
```

Although doing this doesn't make much sense because web crawlers which use this tag usually don't support javascript.

Comment: One-page applications such as Ember and Angular require Javascript to updated the metatags. Crawlers are served a pre-rendered cached version of each page and can thus read the updated metatags.

Comment: Actually, Googlebot has understood Javascript for several years now: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Answer (score 2):

This will make sense when you are using phantom js and prerender the js pages for seo and proxy the bots to the pre-rendered pages instead to the live site.